# how to extract template derived class's method into non-template base class

Tags: c++

I want using polymorphism in C++, I am try to extract method shows in all derived class into base class.

For example:

I have two class, `HouseA` and `HouseB`, they are template class.
And they are derived from base class `BaseHouse`.

```
class BaseHouse
{
public:
    //other thing
private:
};

template <typename Type>
class HouseA : public BaseHouse
{
public:
    HouseA(Type object_input) : object(object_input)
    {
    }
    // other thing about HouseA
    Type &getObject()
    {
        std::cout << "this is House A" << std::endl;
        return object;
    }

private:
    Type object;
};

template <typename Type>
class HouseB : public BaseHouse
{
public:
    HouseB(Type object_input) : object(object_input)
    {
    }
    // other thing about HouseB
    Type &getObject()
    {
        std::cout << "this is House B" << std::endl;
        return object;
    }

private:
    Type object;
};
```

Bacause of polymorphism, we using base class's pointer to access derivated class object. When I need to call method defined in derivated class, I am always transfer base class pointer into derivated class pointer:

```
int main()
{
    HouseA<int> house_a(5);
    int x = house_a.getObject();

    BaseHouse *base_ptr = &house_a;

    // suppose after some complicate calculate calculation
    // we only have the base class pointer can access derivated class object

    HouseA<int> *ptr_a = (HouseA<int> *)base_ptr; //transfer base class pointer into derivated class pointer
    ptr_a->getObject();
    return 0;
}
```

But the derived class `HouseA` and `HouseB` both have the method `getObject`.

## So I want to extract template derived class's method into non-template base class.

## For some reason, we suppose that the base class `BaseHouse` can not be template class.

Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to define a virtual `getObject` in the base class with return type the most common type of derived classes' parameters. If they can be anything, well, then `std::any` is your only option. Or, you can change to architecture and employ the Visitor patter.

Comment: @bipll how could we employ visitor pattern，could you please give an example？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the signature of the derived member depends on the template arguments (as your getObject does on Type) the member cannot be extracted into a non-template base. At least not without removing the ability of the member's signature to vary based on template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly a classical Visitor, but...

Okay, the basic idea is we have to somehow capture and encapsulate templated processing into a single entity ready-to-use in a run-time polymorphic construct.

Let's start with a simple class hierarchy:

```cpp
struct Consumer;

struct Base {
    virtual void giveObject(Consumer const &) const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Derived1: Base {
    Derived1(int x): x(x) {}
    void giveObject(Consumer const &c) const override {
        c(x);
    }
private:
    int x;
};

struct Derived2: Base {
    Derived2(double y): y(y) {}
    void giveObject(Consumer const &c) const override {
        c(y);
    }
private:
    double y;
};
```

So far, it is very simple: the `Base` class has a pure virtual method that accepts an object of type `Consumer` and a concrete implementation of this method is expected to expose to `Consumer` the relevant part of the internal state of its particular implementor (which is a subtype of `Base`). In other words, we have taken that 'virtual template' idiom and hid it inside the `Consumer`. Ok, what could it possibly be?

First option, if you know in advance at compile-time (at source code-time, more exactly) what it could possibly do, i.e. there's only one algorithm of consumption per each object type, and the set of types is fixed, it is quite straightforward:

```cpp
struct Consumer {
    void consume(int x) const { std::cout << x << " is an int.\n"; }
    void consume(double y) const { std::cout << y << " is a double.\n"; }
    template<typename T> void consume(T t) const {
        std::cout << "Default implementation called for an unknown type.\n";
    }
};
```

etc.

More elaborate implementation would allow run-time construction of a templated entity. How is that even possible?

Alexandrescu in his "Modern C++ Design" uses `typeid` to store particular type handlers in a single data structure. In a brief, this could be something like:

```cpp
struct Handler {
    virtual ~Handler() = default; // now it's an empty polymorphic base
};

template<typename T> struct RealHandler: Handler {
    RealHandler(std::function<void(T)> f): f(std::move(f)) {}
    void handle(T x) {
        f(x);
    }
private:
    std::function<void(T)> f;
};

#include <map>
#include <type_info>
#include <functional>

struct Consumer {
    template<typename T> void consume(T t) const {
        auto f{knownHandlers.find(typeid(t))};
        if(f != knownHandlers.end()) {
            RealHandler<T> const &rh{
                dynamic_cast<RealHandler<T> const &>(*f->second)};
            rh.handle(t);
        }
        else {
            // default implementation for unregistered types here
        }
    }
    template<typename T> Consumer &register(std::function<void(T)> f) {
        knownHandlers[typeid(T)] = std::make_unique<RealHandler<T>>(std::move(f));
    }
private:
    std::map<std::type_info, std::unique_ptr<Handler>> knownHandlers;
};
```

Haven't actually tested it, as I don't like typeids and other RTTI much. What I have quickly tested is another solution that requires neither maps nor typeinfo to store handlers in a templated manner. Still it uses a small trick, like how can we possibly pass, keep and retrieve information of an arbitrary type with the same call.

```
struct Consumer {
    Consumer() {}
    template<typename T> void consume(T t) const {
        auto f{setSlot<T>()};
        if(f) f(t);
        else {
            // default implementation for an unset slot
            std::cout << t / 2 << '\n';
        }
    }
    template<typename T>
    std::function<void(T)> &setSlot(
            std::function<void(T)> f = std::function<void(T)>{}) const
    {
        static std::function<void(T)> slot;
        if(f) { // setter
            slot = std::move(f);
        }
        return slot;
    }
};
```

Here, `setSlot()` is used to store a handler for a particular type: when called with a non-empty argument, it stores that argument; and then returns its currently kept value. With `Consumer` so defined, the class hierarchy from above works as:

```cpp
int main() {
    Consumer c;
    c.setSlot<int>([](int x){ std::cout << x << " is an int!\n"; });
    Base const &b1{Derived1{42}};
    Base const &b2{Derived2{3.14}};
    b1.giveObject(c);
    b2.giveObject(c);
}
```

Output:

```
42 is an int!
1.57
```

In the first line we see a message printed by a custom `int` handler; in the second line, a default message is printed for the `double` type, as no custom handler for `double` was installed.

One obvious drawback of this implementation is that handlers are stored in `static` variables thus all `Consumer`s share the same handlers for all types, so `Consumer` here is actually a monostate. At least, you can change implementations for types at run-time, unlike if you had fixed `Consumers` of the very first approach. The maps-of-typeids approach from above shouldn't have this drawback, in exchange for some performance cost.